# glide does not work with me

Tags: java, android, android-glide

i don't know why glide does not work with me 
i put it like that :

```
 Glide.with(this)
            .load("http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/deadpool.jpg")
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .crossFade()
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(imgheader);
```

i add also this to my gradle :

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and internet permission too , 
i try picasso too , but the same , does not work !

### what should i do plaise

i use it in fragment & activity and the same problem

```
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.open_new);
    toolbarLayout= (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    imgheader= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageheader);
    titleView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    infoView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    title =intent.getStringExtra("title");
    date =intent.getStringExtra("date");
    info =intent.getStringExtra("info");
    imgurl =intent.getStringExtra("imgurl");
    id =intent.getIntExtra("id",0);
    show =intent.getStringExtra("show");
    Toast.makeText(this,imgurl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(Uri.parse(imgurl))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .crossFade()
            .error(R.drawable.desktop)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(imgheader);
    imgheader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    titleView.setText(title);
    infoView.setText(info);
```

and in my xml i have this :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:id="@+id/imageheader"
            android:src="@drawable/imgtest"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please include the code for the `imgHeader` `ImageView` defined in XML? Are you sure its visibility is not set to anything other than `View.VISIBLE` anywhere in the project? In case above it not true, try to change the cache strategy to `.RESULT` and see if its loading faster.

Comment: are you in fragment or in activity ? Can you share your full code ? both activity/fragment and layout xml file

Comment: i add my xml and activity code ^^

Comment: Direct pass image url like instead of _Uri.parse(imgurl)_. Like _.load(imgurl)_

Comment: the same , now i see this drawble (  .error(R.drawable.desktop) )

Comment: IS this url it _http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/deadpool.jpg_?. Also call this _imgheader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);_ before u load image url in Glide

Comment: i change it to http://i.imgur.com/rT5vXE1.jpg but the same .. why ! ?

Comment: Its showing my side. Working proper. Now time to go. Bye.

Comment: and why i can't load any image :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's my fault , 
correct uses :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

but i used :

```
<permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>
```